# javascript redraw the page while in function?

Tags: javascript, dom, html

I have a javascript function that loads 100 div's from a xmlhttprequest function. I would like it so that the browser shows them loading one by one, and so the user can see the progress. However with the function below I see nothing until everything is loaded. How can I get the browser to 'redraw' the page after each child div is attached?

```
  window.onLoad = function () 
    {
    var i;
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = httpget('getitem.pl?component=' + i);
      var maindiv = document.getElementById('maindiv');
      maindiv.appendChild(newdiv);
      document.getElementById('progressdiv').innerHTML = 'Progress: ' + i + ' of 100';
      }
    document.getElementById('progressdiv').innerHTML = 'Loaded.';
    }
```

Comment: Which browser do you use? Can you make jsfiddle example?

Comment: what is that `httpget` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it within a function. You need to let the browser breathe, normally using `setTimeout(fn, 0)`.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var i = 1;
  function loop() {

    // loop body

    if (++i <= 100) {
      setTimeout(loop, 0);
    } else {
      // loop done
    }
  }
  loop();
}
```

Javascript and browser's UI are running in the same thread; as long as you keep executing JS, the UI will not update. `setTimeout` will push a new "job" on the queue, and then the `loop` function will exit. This ends the current "job". Next in the queue will be any changes in the UI; when that is done, the next `loop` "job" will commence.

Comment: Thanks, I set a timeout to load the first div, and in that timeout set a timeout for the next div, and so on until they are all loaded.

Comment: Are you sure that `Javascript and browser's UI are running in the same thread`? It seem far more likely that the browser simply waits for scripts to finish executing before updating the UI because there's no point in updating it until all modifications are finished.

Comment: @RobG: [Yes, I'm sure.](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449382308/responsive-interfaces/the_browser_ui_thread)

Comment: While I greatly respect Nicholas Zakas, it would be good to have some other sources. He qualifies the statement with "most browsers…", I'd like to know what research he has to support that opinion.

Comment: You mean like what does the standards say about when the DoM should update and apply?